# Why an image element is not centered although padding is specified?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center an image but when I specify padding, the image element is not centered.

[Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-bartik-4xlw4?file=/index.html)

**HTML**

```html
<div class="imageParent">
            <figure id='img-div'>
                <img class='image card'
                    src='https://img.webmd.com/dtmcms/live/webmd/consumer_assets/site_images/article_thumbnails/other/cat_relaxing_on_patio_other/1800x1200_cat_relaxing_on_patio_other.jpg'
                    alt='Cat sleeping' />
                <figcaption id='img-caption'>
                    <p class='centeredText'> Cat sleeping </p>
                </figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.image {
        background: white;
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 2em 2em 4em 2em;
      }

      @media (max-width: 500px) {
        .image {
          padding: 1em 1em 2em 1em;
        }
      }
```

Comment: Ah, there's much more in that exact question - "why". :) While the provided solution certainly is a good answer (it solves the issue), there're many interesting things running under the carpet here. Have you noticed that dropping that external `<figure>` element - or just resetting its margins with `figure { margin: 0; }` - makes the margins for that image the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `box-sizing: border-box;` for your image. This will help you in making the padding inside the container div. In your scenario the padding will be considered apart from the 100% width of the image. This makes the image to move out of the container due to the extra padding.

[Docs.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

> border-box tells the browser to account for any border and padding in
> the values you specify for an element's width and height. If you set
> an element's width to 100 pixels, that 100 pixels will include any
> border or padding you added, and the content box will shrink to absorb
> that extra width.

```css
.image {
  background: white;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 2em 2em 4em 2em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .image {
    padding: 1em 1em 2em 1em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="imageParent">
  <figure id="img-div">
    <img
      class="image card"
      src="https://img.webmd.com/dtmcms/live/webmd/consumer_assets/site_images/article_thumbnails/other/cat_relaxing_on_patio_other/1800x1200_cat_relaxing_on_patio_other.jpg"
      alt="Cat sleeping"
    />
    <figcaption id="img-caption">
      <p class="centeredText">Cat sleeping</p>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```